# DRF ManyToMany Field getting an error when creating object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a `Rant` model with `Category` linked to it using `ManyToManyField`. I've serialized it but the problem is this error:

```json
{
  "categories": [
    "Expected a list of items but got type \"str\"."
  ]
}
```

These are my serializers:

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"


class RantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Rant
        fields = ('rant', 'slug', 'categories')
```

My `post` method is this:

```py
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = RantSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: can you show your request body?

Comment: @Sumithran This is the body {
  "rant": "string",
  "slug": "string",
  "categories": "string"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced a similar problem. Do the following to solve your issue

1. Install the drf-writable-nested with `pip install drf-writable-nested`
2. Re-write your serializers like so

```
# --- snip ---
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"


class RantSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Rant
        fields = ('rant', 'slug', 'categories')
# ---snip ----
```

The catch here is to import and implement the `WritableNestedModelSerializer` class. Also note that the `serializers.ModelSerializer` super class has been replaced on the serializer where you want to do the nested payload.

3. Trying performing the API calls. You should be good to go.

For more information, refer to this repo's README [here](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you might be send a request with body something like this,

```
{
    "rant": "This is my rant",
    "slug": "my-rant",
    "categories": 1
}
```

Since categories is a ManyToMany relation, it is expecting a list of ids,

Give this a try:

```
{
    "rant": "This is my rant",
    "slug": "my-rant",
    "categories": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: How do I change this to be a string instead of an integer?

Comment: why you want to change that? does't this work for you? if not can you share the error you got?

Comment: i want it to be a string. This is the error that I got {
  "categories": [
    "Expected a list of items but got type \"str\"."
  ]
}This is the payload {
  "rant": "string",
  "slug": "string",
  "categories": "string"
}

Comment: okey, what is the result when you send the request with the body as per mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Doesn't want to submit

Comment: sorry didn't understand that, can you explain a bit about the error you got?

Comment: Here's a screen recording https://share.vidyard.com/watch/crd1WjapHceEyA1E8WNpPU?

Comment: okey can you try with just  [1]

Comment: Same. Doesn't want to submit still. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: that should work, can  you try this in postman or any other rest clients

Comment: Tried to use curl to post data `curl -d "rant=Fifth Rant&slug=fifth-rant&categories=cat" -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/rants/` but got an error `{"detail":"Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request`

Comment: dude you should send, [ categoryId1, categoryId2, ...] otherwise it will give the same error.. even in your curl you are sending the string "cat", thats not valid.

Comment: Try this instead ```curl -d '{"rant":"Fifth Rant","slug":"fifth-rant","categories":[1,2]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/rants/```

Comment: Got this error. i wonder what's wrong with this `{"categories":[{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]},{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]}]}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with serializer, and your serializer is read-only, and threrefore serializer.save() has no effect.

In order to change this behavior, you need to overwrite **serializer** methods: create() and update(), or/and save().

Check this documentation for implementation details: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: updated my rant serializer but it still doesn't save despite the update

Comment: update the serializer code in your question, then I can have a look

Comment: It's already updated